# Spring boot HTTP GET custom validation

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, groovy

I have a controller's method with a getMapping and a pathValue:

```
@ResponseBody
@Validated
@GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE],
value = '/{person}')
PersonResponse getPersonInfo (
    @Valid @PersonValidation
    @PathVariable('person') String personId,
    BindingResult bindingResult
    ) {
//  Abort if received data is not valid
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new BadHttpRequest()
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is validating the uri's personId using my custom validation @PersonValidation but it is not working, the code is not giving any errors but the program never goes into my custom validation class...

¿How can I fix this?
¿How can I validate my path variable with a custom validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Spring have some problems to validate path variables...
First, you need to add a configuration class with a MethodValidationPostProcessor like this one:

```
/**
* this class is required to use our custom path variable validation on 
* the controller class
*/
@Configuration
class ValidatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor()
    }
}
```

Now, on the controller class, it is important to add @Validated annotation

```
@RestController
@Validated
class YourController class {
}
```

now your custom validation on the path variable is gonna work, if you want to catch the exception, add this method inside a exception handler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = [ ConstraintViolationException.class ])
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    String handle(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations()
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder()
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
            strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n")
        }
        return strBuilder.toString()
    }
}
```