# How to customize java spring @NotNull validation error message

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

```
    @POST
    @Path("")
    @Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    TokenDTO login(@ApiParam(value = "The id of the channel used", required = true )  @HeaderParam("channel")  @NotEmpty(message = "email.notempty") String channel) throws Exception;
```

Hello guys, I am trying to validate the channel parameter so it is not empty.
If I parse it empty it just throws me:

```
{
"code": 26,
"message": "Validation Error: :NotEmpty",
"data": [
    {
        "type": "NotEmpty",
        "property": "",
        "value": null,
        "inputType": "body",
        "attributes": null
    }
],
"source": "XXXX",
"type": "ValidationException",
"guid": "965ee91a-99a1-4ae5-b721-6415a80dad23"
}
```

Can you please tell me how can I customize the validation error message?

EDIT: I have seen many articles describing me how to customize the message of a "Field" validation.
But i want to validate a method parameter.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a custom validation annotation instead of modifying and existing one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069805/spring-boot-http-get-custom-validation

Answer (score 1):

In your parameter make sure to add curly braces, so it will be like this

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}") String email
```

Then, define the LocalValidatorFactoryBean in your application configuration:

```
   @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:ValidationMessages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }
```

Finally, create a ValidationMessages.properties file in the classpath containing:

```
email.notempty=E-mail address is required
```

Comment: i created a ValidationMessages.properties file and added the property. I still get the same error